# How to hide the previous row in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When i click first row it shows the output.
When i click second, it is also showing, but the first row is not hided.
It's still displaying.

It should happen for all the rows, not only the first two.

JavaScript code:

```
$('#table_struct tr').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var offset = $this.offset();
    var height = $this.height();
    var order_id = $this.data('order_id');
    $('.menu').remove();
    $.get('getuser.php?order_id=' + order_id, function(table) {
        $('#showmenu').append(table);
        $('.menu').css({
            right: offset.right,
            top: offset.top+height
        });
    });
});
```

index.php

```
          include "db.php";
                        $query = "select * from orders_list";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);

                        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                        if($num_rows >= 1)
                            {

                            echo "<div id='showmenu' class='scroll'>";  
                        echo "<table id='table_struct' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' border='1' width='400' height='30'>
                             <tr class='tr_class' bgcolor='white'>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Select </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> order_id </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> customer_name </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> no_of_pack </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> price </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Weight </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> payment mode </td>



                        </tr>";

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {

                                    $order_id = $row['order_id'];
                                    $_SESSION['order_id'] = $order_id;
                                    echo "<tr height='20' data-order_id='".$row['order_id']."'>
                                    <td align='center'><input type='checkbox' class='case' name='case' value='1'></td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['order_id']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['customer_name']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['number_of_pack']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['price']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['weight']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['payment']."</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</table>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    }


                    if(!mysql_close($con))
                    {
                        echo "failed to close";
                    }
```

getuser.php

```
                 include "db.php";
                 $order_id = intval($_GET['order_id']);
                 $query = "select * from orders_details where order_id=$order_id";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);

                        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                        if($num_rows >= 1)
                            {
                            echo "<div class='menu' class='scroll'>";   
                        echo "<table id='table_struct' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' border='1' width='650' height='30'>
                             <tr class='tr_class' bgcolor='white'>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Product </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Quantity </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Sku </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Price </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Total </td>

                        </tr>";

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                    echo "<tr height='30'> 
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['product']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['quantity']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['sku']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['price']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['total']."</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</table>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    }
```

Comment: Use `hide` or `remove` function of `jquery` with identifier.

Comment: use closest and hide events of jQuery.

Comment: provide html also if possible

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a previous selector...maybe you can use that?
Code taken from jquery documentation page: `$( "li.third-item" ).prev().css( "background-color", "red" );`

Basically you could do: `$('something').click(function() { $(this).prev().hide(); })` or `$(this).parent().prev().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure how PHP works, but if the table you are making is being made dynamicaly (after your javascript has run) then your jquery selector isn't working..

```
$('#table_struct tr').click(function()
```

Use jquery to select the table's container and apply like this instead!

```
$('#tableContainer').on('click', 'tr', function(){/*things*/})
```

By binding the click-event on a "container"s any given child, you know that even if things are added to the container after the pageLoad, the elements will be clickable as the event is bound to the parent, not the element itself.